# Shortest path with a fuel tank

Tags: graph-theory, dynamic-programming

This is an homework question and I'd be happy for some guidance.

Let G=(V,E) be an undirected graph where each vertex represents a city, and the edges have weights that represents travel distances. Some of the cities have gas stations in them. A car starts from vertex s with a gas tank sufficient to travel length L. I need to find the shortest path between s and t so that the car won't run out of gas.

My main thought was to use Floyd–Warshall algorithm with some changes. When we calculate shortestPath(i,j,0) we assign w(i,j) if i has a gas station and L-w(i,j) > 0 , and infinity otherwise. However, for the next steps, I don't know how to add the current fuel status into the calculations.

Thanks.

Comment: It would really help if you'd show [what you have already tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so we wouldn't waste time suggesting ideas that you already know don't work.  You might also find [Jon's blog entry](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) useful.

Comment: @DanPichelman: My main thought was to use Floyd–Warshall algorithm with some changes. When we calculate shortestPath(i,j,0) we assign w(i,j) if i has a gas station and L-w(i,j) > 0 , and infnity otherwise. However, for the next steps, I don't know how to add the current fuel status into the calculations.

Comment: I wonder if [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) might be a better fit, given that you have a known starting and ending point.  When analyzing distance to the "next node", anything over L - "length since last gas station" would be infinity.  If the current node has gas, then "length since last gas station" would reset to zero.  (You'd have to track both "length since last gas station" and "overall length of path" separately).  Not sure if this is right - I haven't done this in a while.  Good luck though, it sounds like a fun problem.

Comment: @Roy: Floyd-Warshall is really better used for finding the shortest paths between **all** pairs of nodes, so Dan Pichelman is correct. The only addition I would make be to simply ensure that a city is not added to the priority queue if traveling to it would run the car out of gas. Otherwise, you'll get just the shortest path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make new weighted graph with vertices: `s`, `t` and cities (`C`) with gas station.

Edges:

- `s-c`, with `c` from `C`, if there is a shortest path between `s` and `c` has length `<= L`,
- `c1-c2`, with `c1`, `c2` from `C`, with length `c1-c2 <= L`,
- `c-t`, with `c` from `C`, with length `c-e <= L`,
- `s-t`, if length `s-t <= L`.

And edge weight set to length `v1-v2`.

Standard Dijkstra on this graph should return skeleton of shortest path you are looking for on original graph.

It is possible to crate new graph 'iteratively' when Dijkstra asks for edges on boundary vertices. Something like, first create `s-c` and `s-t` edges (and vertices), and if there is a demand for `c1-c2` and `c-t` than add these vertices and edges to a graph.